# UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "AppleLanguages") contents issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

I am using Xcode to develop iOS apps, and I recently found this situation, in the debugging console:

```
(lldb) p Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
(String) $R6 = "en"
(lldb) 

(lldb) p UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "AppleLanguages")
([String]?) $R20 = 1 value {
[0] = "en"
}
(lldb)
```

As one can see above, only "en" (the English language) is present in the list.

There is probably nothing strange about that, but what is weird is that I can see this while my phone is set in a different language (French), I have also tried while the phone is in Japanese with the same situation.

The truth is, I do not understand what is going on and would be glad if someone could make clarify this. I expect to see several items in the list, but more importantly I expect to see the language my device is currently set in. In other words:

```
"fr", + possibly some other items
(while being in French)

"ja", + possibly some other items
(while being in Japanese)
```

Running the same debugger command in another app I get:

```
(lldb) p UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "AppleLanguages")
([String]?) $R6 = 14 values {
  [0] = "ja-JP"
  [1] = "fr-JP"
  [2] = "en-JP"
  [3] = "zh-Hant-JP"
  [4] = "zh-Hans-JP"
  [5] = "es-JP"
  [6] = "th-JP"
  [7] = "zh-HK"
  [8] = "ru-RU"
  [9] = "ko-KR"
  [10] = "fi-FI"
  [11] = "de-DE"
  [12] = "bo-JP"
  [13] = "hi-JP"
}
(lldb)
```

This last result is more what I expect to see (since my phone is currently set in Japanese). But what setting in my first app can lead to the result I get. This is the very problem.

For information, I am using Xcode version 11.2 and iOS version 12.4.2.

Comment: What localizations does your app actually support?

Comment: For the time being: English and French.
But does that explain that I see only "en" in the list, while my device language is not even set into English?

Comment: Why do you expect `UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "AppleLanguages")` to do anything at all? It isn’t officially supported anyway. What are you actually trying to find out?

Comment: Also what system is this? Preferred languages work in a new way in iOS 13.

Comment: Up to recently I had always checked Locale.preferredLanguages[0] (which seems to be the same as UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "AppleLanguages")) to find out the preferred language of the user. That's all.

Comment: What is the way to get the user preferred language in 12.4.2 and later then?

Comment: How is it possible to have this in the debugger:
p Locale.preferredLanguages ([String]) $R12 = 1 value {[0] = "en"}
when my phone is in Japanese ? Some setting must be wrong in my app.